# python checking on thread started in different class

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm curious how can I get the status of thread that have been started in a separate class in python.

So currently I have:

```
class VideoCapture:
    def record:
        Thread(name='uploading', target=self.upload, args=(upload_queue)).start()
```

In a seperate file `main.py` I have an instance of `VideoCapture`.
I want to be able to check the status of the thread "uploading" by typing something like `VideoCapture.uploading.isAlive()`. However I get the error that VideoCapture has no object uploading. So how can I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the thread as something that is part of the class, then after that you have a means of accessing it later on.

```
class VideoCapture:
    def __init__():
        self.uploading = None
    def record:
       self.uploading = Thread(name='uploading', target=self.upload, args=(upload_queue)).start()
```

Now somewhere else you have:

```
video_capture = VideoCapture()
video_capture.record()
if video_capture.uploading.isAlive(): 
    # do something
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. The first run i'm calling on video_capture.uploading.isAlive():  before the thread has been defined. so it's complaining that uploading is a none type. i'm currently letting it be a dummy thread with  self.uploading = Thread() and then reassigning it to self.uploading = Thread(name='uploading', target=self.upload, args=(upload_queue)).start() is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: That really depends on what you want to achieve, what should it do if no call to uploading() has been made? Will the VideoCapture object be used after this? But it is probably better to ask this in a separate thread ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's method [`is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) in [`Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) object, so basically you need just use it:

```
class VideoCapture:
    def record(self):
        # don't forget to add it on __init__
        self.uploading = Thread(name='uploading', target=self.upload, args=(upload_queue)).start()

tmp = VideoCapture()
tmp.record()
tmp.uploading.is_alive()  # here it is
```